# Access Outlook folder through C#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm trying to access the Outlook inbox as per this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268754(v=vs.80).aspx

but it seems like the default folder it's accessing is empty. Is there some settings that I need to change in either Outlook 2010 or in this code?

Answer (score 0):

I was checking the example you provided ,

This example requires:

**A folder named TestFileSave at the root of the C directory.**

Before you excute the code, you have to create it manully or in code , if you create it in code you may get security issues , so it's better you manually creat it or use another drive instead of C.

And plesae be so kind enough to provide us with the exception if you get any error becuase that will make us easy to help you

Comment: Yes, i have created this folder. I don't get any exception it's just that when I have
    Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            String test = "num mail:" + inbox.ShowItemCount + "";
            MessageBox.Show(test, "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

It's zero, which i don't understand, since I can clearly see couple thousand emails.